Restricting Branch Permissions for Specific Users in Azure DevOps
I have a project, and in one branch of that project, I need to restrict access so that only specific users can pull, push, and create branches. How can I set this up in Azure? I'm not understanding it; please help me.

To apply branch permissions to a specific project, navigate to your project > Repos > Manage repositories > Security, then select the users or groups and deny the permissions in the right-side panel.

I hope this helps to resolve your query.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops

ok sir Thank you but i already reffered this   learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/
but  it was not working

i alrady tried what you suggested but it was not happening to me is there any solutions to do this


Restricting Branch Permissions for Specific Users in Azure DevOps

In order to restrict access to only specific users or groups on the branch level, you can follow the steps below.

Go to your project > Repos > Branches > Select your branch.



Open the branch security settings and select the users or groups. Set the permissions as per your requirements


Reference: Set branch permissions

i alrady tried what you suggested but it was not happening to me is there any solutions to do this

You can check if the assigned user is part of any Azure Devops Groups.

no sir assigned user was not part of any Azure Devops Groups

If assigned user is the part of any one of the Azure Devops Groups is there any possibilities to Restricting Branch Permissions ??

If a user is part of any Azure DevOps group, they will, by default, inherit permissions from that group. To restrict access, remove the user from the existing group and create a new group with the required restricted permissions. Then, assign the branch security permissions to the new group.

still That assigned user able to push and pull the  perticlur pranch (restricted branch). sir it was not working

Have you verified that user is not part any group?

no  assigned user is not part of any group sir.

Do you on thing , Go to your project > select Repos > Manage Repositories securities > then select the user who wants to restrict the permission. Follow this steps and confirm.

Ok sir i will try

When I tried your suggestion, it was applying to the entire project instead of a specific branch, sir. Please help me correct this.

For the specific branch above is the process.Follow the Link :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops for mor details.

same thing i already tried but it is not working sir

Kindly follow the steps mentioned in MS Doc; if still not working, you can raise a support ticket.

ok sir thank your support
